# Detect USB after Safely Remove USB

Tags: windows, usb

I am currently developing an application which

*copies all files from USB, when detected, to my local hard-drive*

As I mentioned that I'm still developing, so I have to *plug-in* and *plug-out* my USB again and again to test my code.

Is there a way to detect USB again after **Safely Remove Hardware**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from kolypto on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/44339/re-mount-usb-device-after-removal-on-windows):

> When you "safely remove" a USB HDD - it stops spinning. I believe there's a USB command to turn the device off (sleep mode, actually). So the thing you need is how to turn the device back on.
>
> The application [Safelyremove](http://safelyremove.com/) has a command-line tool that is capable of returning the device back: "Returning just stopped device back!".
>
> It is shareware, but it works :)

Comment: Thanks @Keltari and kolypto.
You saved my USB and my laptop's USB port.